# Linux - unzip file in place

Tags: linux, zip, compression

I need to download VM image provided in zip. Zip is 10 gb, unpacked VM image around 16gb and I have around 20gb space on disk. Is it possible to unzip downloaded file "in-place"?

Comment: `bsdtar` does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2715/7167).

The index of a ZIP file is at the end of the file. This means, you have to download everything, before you can start doing anything with the ZIP file. Even with other tools like `bsdtar` you have to store everything of the ZIP file somewhere.

All you can do is writing the download into a RAM disk. ;-)

Comment: Welp. That's what i did in the end :|

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15321699/402322) user Adam described how to mount zip file using virtual filesystem and unzip file to Your local filesystem.