# Is it possible to download just part of a ZIP file using python zipfile library

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-zipfile

I was wondering is there any way by which I can download only a part of a .rar or .zip file without downloading the whole file ? There is a zip file containing files A,B,C and D. I only need A. Can I somehow, use zipfile module so that i can only download 1 file  ?

i am trying below code:

```
 r = c.get(file)
    z = ZipFile.ZipFile(BytesIO(r.content)) 
    for file1 in z.namelist():
        if 'time' not in file1:
            print("hi")
            z.extractall(file1,download_path + filename)
```

This code is downloading whole zip file and only extracting specific one. Can i somehow download only the file i Need. 
There is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543214/is-it-possible-to-download-just-part-of-a-zip-archive-e-g-one-file) but it shows only approch by command line in linux. That question dosent address how it can be done using python liabraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to download just part of a ZIP archive (e.g. one file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543214/is-it-possible-to-download-just-part-of-a-zip-archive-e-g-one-file)

Comment: @Juggernaut nope. that is in unix context. I am asking if its possible using the python code. Nothing of sort is mentioned in that question. I already checked that question. And asked mine

Answer (score 1):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543214/is-it-possible-to-download-just-part-of-a-zip-archive-e-g-one-file) @Juggernaut mentioned in a comment is actually very helpful, as it points you in the direction of the solution.

You need to create a replacement for Bytes.IO that returns the necessary information to `ZipFile`. You will need to get the length of the file, and then get whatever sections `ZipFile` asks for.

How large are those file? Is it really worth the trouble?

Comment: Yeah the file which i want to ignore is around 1.5 gb each. and there are 10 files like that

Comment: zmbq can you wxplain a bit how that can be done. i couldnt figure that out

Answer (score 0):

Use remotezip: https://github.com/gtsystem/python-remotezip. You can install it using pip:

```
pip install remotezip
```

Usage example:

```py
from remotezip import RemoteZip


with RemoteZip("https://path/to/zip/file.zip") as zip_file:
    for file in zip_file.namelist():
        if 'time' not in file:
            print("hi")
            zip_file.extract(file, path="/path/to/extract")
```

Note that to use this approach, the web server from which you receive the file needs to support the [Range header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range).